# DataTemplate中におけるUserControlのBinding

Tags: c#, uwp

問題はListViewなどのItemSourceからDataTemplateでUserControlを呼び出したとき、その中のBindingがうまくいかないことです。

作成したUserControlは以下の通りで、

MyUserControl1.cs

```
namespace EditableTextBox
{
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public MyUserControl1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Block.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Box.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }

    private void Box_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Block.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Box.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
}
```

MyUsercontrol1.xaml

```
<UserControl
x:Class="EditableTextBox.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:EditableTextBox"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock Visibility ="Visible" Name="Block" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
    <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed" Name="Box" Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" LostFocus="Box_LostFocus"/>
</Grid>
```

そしてUserControlを呼び出すためのMainPage.xamlが以下の通りです。

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace EditableTextBox
{
/// <summary>
/// それ自体で使用できる空白ページまたはフレーム内に移動できる空白ページ。
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        test = "test";
        test2 = new List<string>();
        test2.Add("1");
        test2.Add("2");
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public string test { get; set; }
    public List<string> test2 { get; set; }
}
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page
x:Class="EditableTextBox.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:EditableTextBox"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <local:MyUserControl1 Text="{x:Bind test,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="304,227,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="568" Height="35"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind test2,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="416" Margin="309,380,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="617">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <local:MyUserControl1 Text="{Binding}"></local:MyUserControl1>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

本来なら
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
と表示させたいのですが、

現在のコードですと
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
のように表示されます。
ご教示お願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

ユーザーコントロールの `this.DataContext = this;` を削除してみて下さい。
DataContext が意図しないものになっているだけの様に思えます。